# php получение значения полей

Tags: php

Есть `html`:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input name="testname" value="1">
   <input name="testname" value="2">
   <input name="testname" value="3">
   <input name="testname" value="4">
   <input name="testname" value="5">
   <input name="testname" value="6">
   <input name="testname" value="7">
   <input name="testname" value="HELLO!!!">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Соответственно, у всех полей одинаковое значение атрибута `name`. Изменить атрибут `name` никак нельзя.

Сам вопрос: как получить значения ВСЕХ полей через `php`? При попытке обратиться к `$_POST['testname']` `php` возвращает только ПОСЛЕДНЕЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ (т.е. слово HELLO!!!).

`var_dump($_POST)` возвращает:

```
array(1) {["testname"]=> string(8) "HELLO!!!" }
```

Возможно ли как - нибудь исправить работу `php` скрипта, и сделать так, чтобы он показывал все значения полей?

Comment: Сделай за меня? Почему нельзя `name` менять?

Comment: @doox911 Менять атрибут name нельзя, так как html - формы предоставляет другой веб - сервер, доступ к которому я не имею

Comment: Врятли это возможно, но чем черт не шутит... `file_get_contents("php://input");`
Если там их нету - это невозможно

Comment: Очень интересный интерфейс))

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в file_get_contents("php://input"); есть ВСЕ значения, но вот вопрос - как их получить?

Comment: Что значит как? вам дать готовое решение как парсить RAW POST DATA?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков сделал так: parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data); var_dump($data); Но все равно в массиве $data находится только последнее значение.......

Comment: Если менять форму нельзя, то вы никак не получите массив всех значений. И это проблема не PHP, а особенность работы браузера.

Comment: @P.Fateev посмотрел панель разработчика, браузер передает ВСЕ значения ВСЕХ полей. А вот php берет только последнее.

Comment: Логично что так вы не получите значение, нужно ручками разбирать и складывать в массив =)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = explode('&', $input);
```

В результате `$array` будет содержать такой массив:

```
array:8 [
    0 => "testname=1"
    1 => "testname=2"
    2 => "testname=3"
    3 => "testname=4"
    4 => "testname=5"
    5 => "testname=6"
    6 => "testname=7"
    7 => "testname=HELLO%21%21%21"
]
```

который вы можете преобразовать дальше по своему усмотрению, например, так:

```
$array = array_map(function($item) {
    return urldecode(explode('=', $item)[1]);
}, $array);
```

После этого получится:

```
array:8 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
    3 => "4"
    4 => "5"
    5 => "6"
    6 => "7"
    7 => "HELLO!!!"
]
```